# Django migrations not pushing to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, heroku-postgres

I have updated a Django blog to use slug urls `<slug:slug>/` instead of id `<int:pk>/`. I also added a slugField to the Article model, and converted all hrefs to `article.slug`. Ran migrations and everything worked fine locally. However, when I pushed to Heroku I got an error.

This is what happens when I attempt to save a new article.

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/articles/article/
column articles_article.slug does not exist
LINE 1: ...ticles_article"."id", "articles_article"."title", "articles_...
                                                             ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://***********.herokuapp.com/admin/articles/article/
Django Version: 2.1.4
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
column articles_article.slug does not exist
LINE 1: ...ticles_article"."id", "articles_article"."title", "articles_...
                                                             ^
```

I checked my Heroku Postgress database and I found that the new slug column hadn't been added even though I did migrations. I'm not exactly sure what to do next. I'm currently searching for ways to manually update the heroku postgress, but if there's a less invasive way to solve this problem I'm all ears.

Comment: Did you properly migrate your database? (so `manage.py migrate`?)

Comment: Yes. I did `python manage.py migrate` and `makemigrations`. Did it a second time for good measure just before the push to heroku.

Comment: Did you run your migrations _on Heroku_? **`heroku run`** `python manage.py migrate` (after committing and deploying the new migration files generated by `migrate`)? Your local database and your Heroku database are different, and they need to be migrated separately. (Note that you shouldn't be running `makemigrations` on Heroku. That just happens locally.)

Comment: Okay so I've been under the impression that I shouldn't do either migraine or make migrations for heroku after the initial push. Why is migrate safe for heroku but makemigrations isnt?

Comment: Because makemigrations, like the name implies, *makes* the migration files. Those are part of your code base. You make them locally and add them to the git repo. Then you push that code to Heroku, after which you need to actually apply them to the database, which you do by running migrate *on Heroku*.

Comment: You guys were right on the mark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first verify that the migration was executed (heroku)

```
verify that the last migration of the article model is in the django_migrations table
```

In case you can't find it, make sure you have updated migrations (local)

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

run the migration in db production (heroku)

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: After reading other threads about migrations for django and heroku, I've been under the impression that I shouldn't make migrations on heroku. Is there anything I should be aware of before attempting this?

Comment: Before making changes to the production database make a backup. This will allow to reverse changes. You should always do it to avoid any loss of information

Comment: Thank you. That did it!

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to make migrations first then migrate? It's noted backward in your comment above.  Also, are you sure you applied the migrations to your production database?  It requires a settings flag added to the migrate command to point to your production settings/db location.

Comment: It was in the proper order.